# Target coordinates given estimate distance from multiple points

Tags: algorithms

I have a device that emits a probe signal, let it be called X. The location of the device is unknown. I have multiple readings of the probe signal in different GPS coordinates spread over an area , along with the signal's strength for each reading, which is proportional to the distance from the device. Assuming I'm on a flat terrain so the problem is reduced to a 2D cartesian plane, how to estimate the position of X ?

Comment: This is either not so hard or potentially very hard, depending on whether you are assuming X is on the surface you mention and if so, whether you have some sort of description/ what kind of description you have of the surface you are trying to find X on.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P_1, \dotsc, P_m$ be the points on the surface you known. Let $d_1,\dotsc, d_m$ be the measured distances. 
Let $X^*$ denote your "true" position.

Assume that the measure error is additiv and i.i.d normal distributed with zero mean (it is not that realistic):
$$ \| X^* - P_i \| - d_i \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma). $$
Then, you could try to fit $X$ in least square sense, that is
$$ \min_{X}\sum_{i=1}^m (\|X-P_i\| - d_i)^2. $$

Assume the distance is the Euclidean distance. You could avoid differentiating the square root by minimizing
$$ \sum_{i=1}^m (\|X-P_i\|_2^2 - d_i^2)^2 $$
instead. However, $\|X-P_i\|_2^2 - d_i^2$ is not normal anymore!

Both problem can be solved using a Gauss-Newton type method.

You could constrain $X$ on a surface. However, this is in fact more difficult to solve. Although there are standard methods.

Comment: It would be helpful to state under what assumptions this optimization problem gives the "best guess" for $X$.

Comment: You haven't defined, what best guess is. Assume the measure error is additive normal, it would be natural for least square. Notice that squaring the distance does change the distribution of the error. However it is standard trick do avoid the square root. You could implement it without squaring.

Comment: Exactly, I haven't defined "best guess" because I don't think that so far it actually is definitively definable according to OP's post. Yet you gave an answer. So all I was saying was, you should state in which statistical sense (e.g., MLE in a certain likelihood model being maximized) your optimization problem gives the "best" answer.

Comment: In fact, I haven't said that it would be the "best" answer. It is just intuition considered what OP wrote.

Comment: Fair enough. There are some glaring gaps in the problem description, like what kind of model the errors should follow and if Gaussian, then whether the variance of that Gaussian error is constant or we should assume different variances and use a prior on variance. It wasn't even clear to me whether we should assume $X$ is on the "surface" since a surface was mentioned. If OP comments that your answer adequately addresses their question, I'll give +1 because your framework is very natural, and moreover gives a convex minimization problem which is easy to solve with a computer.

Comment: @user2566092 It isn't convex. I think I added enough background ... :)